# PhantomJS doesn't run .create()

Tags: npm, async-await, phantomjs

Hardware - Macbook Pro 2019 - Catalina 10.15.5
using Visual Studio Code

In my project we have the following issue;

On a Linux machine it is working, on a Windows machine it is working, on my machine is NOT working.

The code that is not working is this one.

```
phantom.create().then(function (ph) {
            ph.createPage().then(function (page) {
                page.property('paperSize', {
                    format: 'A4',
                    orientation: 'portrait',
                    margin: '0'
                }).then(function () {
```

it is crashing on the phantom.create() function.

I tried to do variations, to see the objects getting built, like,

```
ph = phantom.create();
            console.log('after the phantom create ');
            console.log(ph);
            console.log('this is the ph **');
                (async function (ph) {
                page = ph.createPage().then(
                    function (page) {
                        page.property('paperSize', {
                            format: 'A4',
                            orientation: 'portrait',
                            margin: '0'
```

Still crashing.

Using wait and async

```
(async function() {
            ph = await phantom.create();
            page = await instance.createPage();
            ph.createPage().then(function (page) {
                page = page;
                page.property('paperSize', {
                    format: 'A4',
                    orientation: 'portrait',
                    margin: '0'
                       }).
```

In terminal when I do:

```
Node > require('phantom').create()
```

I get the following

```
> require('phantom').create()
Promise {
  Phantom {
  logger: 
   { info: [Function],
     debug: [Function],
     error: [Function],
     warn: [Function] },
  process: 
   ChildProcess {
     domain: [Domain],
     _events: [Object],
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _closesNeeded: 3,
     _closesGot: 0,
     connected: false,
     signalCode: null,
     exitCode: null,
     killed: false,
     spawnfile: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs',
     _handle: [Process],
     spawnargs: [Array],
     pid: 14804,
     stdin: [Socket],
     stdout: [Socket],
     stderr: [Socket],
     stdio: [Array] },
  commands: Map {},
  events: Map {},
  heartBeatId: 
   Timeout {
     _called: false,
     _idleTimeout: 100,
     _idlePrev: [TimersList],
     _idleNext: [TimersList],
     _idleStart: 3640,
     _onTimeout: [Function: bound heartBeat],
     _timerArgs: undefined,
     _repeat: 100,
     _destroyed: false,
     domain: [Domain],
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 40,
     [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 6 } },
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
```

When I use the debugger it's crashing on line

```
ph = phantom.create();
```

and resume debugger and then pause it's stuck on async_hooks.js - line const fn = function(asyncId) giving an enless loop until I get a timeout.

```
function emitHookFactory(symbol, name) {
  // Called from native. The asyncId stack handling is taken care of there
  // before this is called.
  // eslint-disable-next-line func-style
  const fn = function(asyncId) {
    active_hooks.call_depth += 1;
    // Use a single try/catch for all hook to avoid setting up one per
    // iteration.
    try {
      for (var i = 0; i < active_hooks.array.length; i++) {
        if (typeof active_hooks.array[i][symbol] === 'function') {
          active_hooks.array[i][symbol](asyncId);
        }
      }
```

I also tried changing the launch.json and adding

```
"skipFiles": [
        "inspector_async_hook.js",
        "async_hooks.js",
        "node_internals/**/*.js"
        ],
```

Still stucks on async_hooks.js though.

Any ideas what might be the reason?
Should I change to a Windows machine?

I'm installing a VM in the meantime.